# Scaling Amplitude After Windowing FFT to Recover Correct Amplitude

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to apply a Hann window to a sinusoidal signal with the idea of applying an FFT to recover the frequency and the amplitude.  This is a canonical case I have created to increase my understanding before I move onto my data (real time signal where I want to accurately determine the frequency content and amplitude).  In the code below I need to multiple by an additional factor of 2.0 to recover the amplitudes.  I understand multiplying by 2/N but now I am multiplying by 4/N.  Has anyone come across this or can anyone provide an explanation to why this is?  Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# first create the time signal, which has two frequencies 13.2 hz and 43.9 hz
f_s = 100.0 # Hz  sampling frequency
f = 1.0 # Hz
time = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 1/f_s)
x = 5 * np.sin(13.2 * 2 * np.pi * f * time) + 3 * np.sin(43.9 * 2 * np.pi * f * time)
x = x + np.random.randn(len(time)) #inject some noise

# apply hann window and take the FFT
win = np.hanning(len(x))
FFT = np.fft.fft(win * x) * 2.0  # IT SEEMS I NEED AN ADDITIONAL FACTOR OF 2 TO RECOVER THE AMPLITUDES
n = len(FFT)
freq_hanned = np.fft.fftfreq(n, 1/f_s)  
half_n = np.ceil(n/2.0)
fft_hanned_half = (2.0 / n) * FFT[:half_n]
freq_hanned_half = freq_hanned[:half_n]

# and plot
plt.plot(freq_hanned_half, np.abs(fft_hanned_half))
plt.xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
```

Comment: This won't be alot of help, but I'll just say that FFT normalization can get confusing, especially since not everyone does it the same way.  Some like the "2" in the forward transform, but not the reverse.  Some like it in the reverse but not the forward.  Some "split" the 2, putting a $\sqrt{2}$ in both forward and reverse.  I would just suggest reading the np.fft documentation very carefully paying particualr attention to what it says about normalization.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I can agree it can get a little hairy.  My question has more to do with the Hann Window.  If I don't use the Hann Window and just np.fft.fft(x), I then only need to multiple by 2/n (which makes sense to me).  It is only with the window I effectively need to multiple by 4/n and I am unsure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mean value of the von Hann window is (approximately) 0.5, for `N=1000` you have

```
>>> N=1000 ; print sum(np.hanning(N))/N
0.4995
>>>
```

Does this explain the necessity of multiplying by two to recover the discrete amplitudes?